# formArrayName multidimensional

Tags: angular

Não estou conseguindo referenciar o formArrayName="complementos" que fica dentro do formArrayName="items"

Recebo um erro no console

```
ERROR Error: "Cannot find control with path: 'items -> complementos'"
```

o array items eu consegui percorrer.

Código utilizado.

```
formProduto: FormGroup;
items: FormArray;
complementos: FormArray;

initializeFormProduto() {
    this.formProduto = this.fb.group({
      fileimg: this.fb.control(''),
      nome: this.fb.control(''),
      descricao: this.fb.control(''),
      vl_venda: this.fb.control(''),
      id_cardapio: this.fb.control(''),
      bo_segunda: this.fb.control('true'),
      bo_terca: this.fb.control('true'),
      bo_quarta: this.fb.control('true'),
      bo_quinta: this.fb.control('true'),
      bo_sexta: this.fb.control('true'),
      bo_sabado: this.fb.control('true'),
      bo_domingo: this.fb.control('true'),

      items: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          categoria: this.fb.control(""),
          qtdmin: this.fb.control(""),
          qtdmax: this.fb.control(""),
          bo_obrigatorio: this.fb.control(""),
          complementos: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.group({
              nome: this.fb.control(""),
              descricao: this.fb.control(""),
              valor: this.fb.control(""),
              bo_pausar: this.fb.control(""),
            })
          ]),
        })
      ]),

    })
  }
```

Html.

```
<form [formGroup]='formProduto' novalidate>
    <form-wizard>
        <wizard-step [title]="'Produto'" [isValid]="formProduto.valid">
            <!-- <h1>Step1</h1> -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-3'>
                        <input style="display: none" type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput
                            formControlName='fileimg'>
                        <div class="uploadArquivoProduto"
                            [style.background-image]="'url(' + img + ' )' | safeHtml: 'style' "> </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-neutro btn-upload" (click)="fileInput.click()" style="width: 100%">Imagem
                            Produto</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-5'>
                        <label class="control-label" for='nome'>Nome</label>
                        <app-input-container errorMessage='Campo obrigatório' label='nome'>
                            <input class='form-control' placeholder='' formControlName="nome">
                        </app-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-4'>
                        <label class="control-label" for='nome'>Nome da Categoria</label>
                        <app-input-container errorMessage='Campo obrigatório' label='nome'>
                            <input class='form-control' placeholder='' formControlName="id_cardapio">
                        </app-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-9'>
                        <label class="control-label" for='nome'>Descrição</label>
                        <app-input-container errorMessage='Campo obrigatório' label='nome'>
                            <textarea rows="3" class='form-control' placeholder=''
                                formControlName="descricao"></textarea>
                        </app-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-4'>
                        <label class="control-label" for='nome'>Preço</label>
                        <app-input-container errorMessage='Campo obrigatório' label='nome'>
                            <input class='form-control' placeholder='' formControlName="vl_venda">
                        </app-input-container>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>




        </wizard-step>

        <wizard-step [title]="'Disponibilidade'">
            <h1></h1>
            <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-12'>
                <label class="control-label" for='bo_preco_fixo'>
                    <h4>Dias em que o produto estára disponível</h4>
                </label>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="dom" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" formControlName="bo_domingo">
                    <label for="dom">Dom</label>

                    <input id="seg" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" formControlName="bo_segunda">
                    <label for="seg">Seg</label>

                    <input id="ter" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" formControlName="bo_terca">
                    <label for="ter">Ter</label>

                    <input id="quar" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" formControlName="bo_quarta">
                    <label for="quar">Qua</label>

                    <input id="qui" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" formControlName="bo_quinta">
                    <label for="qui">Qui</label>

                    <input id="sex" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" formControlName="bo_sexta">
                    <label for="sex">Sex</label>

                    <input id="sab" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" formControlName="bo_sabado">
                    <label for="sab">Sab</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </wizard-step>
        <wizard-step [title]="'Complementos'">
            <button class="btn btn-lg  v-middle" (click)="adicionarFk()">
                <i class="iconesExemplos pli-add"></i> Adicionar categoria
            </button>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <pre>
                        {{formProduto.value | json}}
                    </pre>

                <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of formProduto.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
                    <div class="panel panel-light">
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="height: auto!important;">
                            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                <div class="row padding-15">
                                    <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-6'>
                                        <label class="control-label" for='nome'>Categoria</label>
                                        <input class='form-control' formControlName="categoria" placeholder="categoria">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-2'>
                                        <label class="control-label" for='nome'>Qtd Min</label>
                                        <input class='form-control' formControlName="qtdmin" placeholder="qtdmin">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-2'>
                                        <label class="control-label" for='nome'>Qtd Max</label>
                                        <input class='form-control' formControlName="qtdmax" placeholder="qtdmax">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-2'>
                                        <!-- <label class="control-label" for='nome'>Obrigatório</label>
                                            <input class='form-control' formControlName="bo_obrigatorio"
                                                placeholder="bo_obrigatorio"> -->

                                        <div class="checkbox" style="margin-top:28px">
                                            <input id="bo_obrigatorio-{{i}}" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox"
                                                formControlName="bo_obrigatorio">
                                            <label for="bo_obrigatorio-{{i}}">Obrigatório</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" formArrayName="complementos"> <!-- esse é o trecho com erro -->
                            <button class="btn btn-lg  v-middle" (click)="adicionarComplementoFk()">
                                <i class="iconesExemplos pli-add"></i> Adicionar Complemento
                            </button>

                            <div >
                                <div *ngFor="let complemento of item.controls.complementos.value; let i = index;">
                                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                        <div class="row padding-15">
                                            <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-6'>
                                                <label class="control-label" for='nome'>nome</label>
                                                <input class='form-control' formControlName="nome" placeholder="nome">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-2'>
                                                <label class="control-label" for='nome'>descricao</label>
                                                <input class='form-control' formControlName="descricao"
                                                    placeholder="descricao">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-2'>
                                                <label class="control-label" for='nome'>valor</label>
                                                <input class='form-control' formControlName="valor" placeholder="valor">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group is-empty col-md-2'>
                                                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-top:28px">
                                                    <input id="bo_pausar-{{i}}" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox"
                                                        formControlName="bo_pausar">
                                                    <label for="bo_pausar-{{i}}">Pausar</label>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </wizard-step>

        <div [ngSwitch]="isCompleted">
            <div *ngSwitchDefault>
            </div>
            <div *ngSwitchCase="true">
                <h4>Thank you! You have completed all the steps.</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form-wizard>
</form>
```

Comment: No lugar do [formGroupName]="i", tente colocar [formGroup]="item".

Comment: o erro está acontecendo antes dessa trecho, lá em formArrayName="complementos". Console => ERROR Error: "Cannot find control with path: 'items -> complementos'"

Comment: acho que vc tem que colocar o complementos dentro do seu outro ngfor

Comment: @EduardoVargas ele já está dentro do for item, fiz o {{complemento | json}} e ele printou.

Comment: Tenta criar um stackblitz com o seu código ia ficar mais facil te ajudar

Comment: @EduardoVargas, voce estava certo, realmente complementos não estava dentro do <div formArrayName="items". Obrigado. Me deparei com outro problema, fiz o stackblitz, se tiver como voce dar uma olhada. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/384214